# How do I get access to a Pure-Path console app for a Texas Instruments TAS5754M audio chip? TI makes it impossible to find an answer

Tags: audio, texas-instruments

I am in the process of repairing a bi-amped speaker with a TAS5754M amplifier in it. I can communicate with the chip over I2S and the signal flow is also working.
The only thing that is left to fix is the crossover filter (and other DSP eventually) for the drivers.

It is my understanding that in order to programm the DSP on the TAS5754M, you need to get a register-dump from the Pure-Path console doftware. There seem to be no other register maps for the DSP anywhere.

I requested access to the purepath console software, thinking I would just be able to access the TS5754M app in it, but no, in the GUI it is telling me that there are no available EVM apps to install and to contact the "TI Team" to get access to the apps.

I have replied to the "access to PPC granted" mails to get access to the apps. I have also contacted support about the topic.

All they tell me is either:

1. I already have access to the PPC software.
2. To request access to PPC and the TAS5754M app on the TAS5754M website.

When I then request access to PPC and TAS5754M app from the correct link I get a reply mail saying I have already been granted access to PPC.

I will be asking TI support about this again, but I expect them to tell me just the same thig over and over again.

I cannot ask about this on the TI-Forums because I don't have a valid company mail.

Maybe someone has experience with this and knows a solution for my problem.

[image: Pure Path Console GUI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue got resolved.

I had downloaded PPC 3, which doesn't support the TAS5754M.

The installer for PPC 2 which does support it was found in the secure resources submenu on the TI website. In there I also found the cfg files for the TAS5754M.

Although I can now design my DSP chain for the chip in software I cannot get the register dump for the initializiation on my microcontroller (grayed out,) which only works once connected to an eval-board that costs 300+$.